# How do I reverse an epub that turns right to left?

Tags: epub, apple-books

I have an epub book that turns its pages right to left. The text is still left to right, but I press `←` in iBooks to turn to the second page from the first, etc. My other epubs function normally. How can I reverse the order of the pages?

Comment: The other ebooks still work properly, i.e. you did not accidently change a setting in your reader?

Comment: Is this a epub that you made? If so, have you set the page progression direction?

Comment: @Anthon, yes, my other ebooks are fine

Comment: @beaker, nope, but is there a way to change the progression direction within the file?

Comment: Can you post the opf and a section of the html including the opening html tag?

Answer (score 2):

This might not apply in your case, but my response was getting too long for comments.

*If* you have an epub3 *and* you have access to the files, you can set the page progression direction.

If you look [here](http://epubzone.org/news/epub-3-and-global-language-support) at the section titled **Global Direction** you'll see that you can set the direction globally in `content.opf`:

```
<spine toc="..." page-progression-direction="rtl">
```

In your case, you would want to use the opposite, `"ltr"`. The next section **Content Direction** shows how to set the direction for individual html files:

```
<html dir="rtl"
   ...
</html>
```

I can't really say why iBooks is rendering this particular epub with rtl page direction, but there is this note in the Global Directions paragraph:

> There is no default value when this attribute is omitted; the reading system will render the content in whatever is its default manner.

Answer (score 0):

If the opf declares a language that is read right-to-left, iBooks will paginate that book that way, regardless of the language of the HTML pages.

It's worth double checking that the only language in the opf is the language of the title.

Comment: Dual English-Arabic copies of the Qu'ran usually paginate right to left and there is no way to change this behavior. A Word document that is created on an Arabic (or Hebrew) enabled computer will often read right to left if the language is English but the template is set to Arabic or Hebrew.